# Bounds on the AM-GM gap?

Tags: inequality, upper-lower-bounds, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

I have the expression $\frac{1}{2}(a_1+a_2) - \sqrt{a_1 a_2}$ and I need to upperbound it. Note that this is the "slack in the AM-GM inequality". In my specific case, $0\leq a_1,a_2 \leq 1$. Are there any useful bounds for this? I was not able to find anything relevant.

Comment: You have the exact expression $-\frac12(\sqrt{a_1}-\sqrt{a_2})^2$ that you can play with.

Comment: Good point, I have fixed that

Comment: When $0 \leqslant a_1, a_2 \leqslant 1$ the difference is $\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt a_1 - \sqrt a_2)^2$ which surely has upper bound $\frac{1}{2}$, right?